# Sum group of rows

Tags: mysql, group-by

Lets say i have a table like this

```
+------------+---------+
| fecha      | cuota   |
+------------+---------+
| 2000-12-17 | 2345.06 |
| 2007-02-26 | 1666.45 |
| 2007-02-26 | 4011.51 |
| 2007-02-26 | 4011.51 |
| 2007-02-26 | 4011.51 |
| 2007-02-26 | 4011.51 |
| 2007-02-26 | 2287.52 |
| 2007-12-28 | 1723.99 |
| 2007-12-28 | 4011.51 |
| 2007-12-28 | 4011.51 |
| 2007-12-28 | 252.99  |
+------------+---------+
```

How can i sum the rows that have the same date to get something like

```
+------------+---------+
| fecha      | cuota   |
+------------+---------+
| 2000-12-17 | 2345.06 |
| 2007-02-26 | 2000.00 |
| 2007-12-28 | 10000.00|
+------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
SELECT fecha, SUM(cuota) as cuota
FROM myTable
GROUP BY fecha;
```

Simply put it will group all the dates together and then sum all the cuota-values in each group.

Comment: LOL, i got it myself, i was going to answer my own question with that exact query, thanks a lot, it works! – Puerto AGP just now edit

Answer (score 1):

does this work?

```
select fecha, sum(cuota) from yourTable group by fecha
```

Comment: LOL, i got it myself, i was going to answer my own question with that exact query, thanks a lot, it works!